# SQL ReportServer 2005 on Win Server 2008 & IIS7 gets "unable to load client print control"

Tags: iis, reportserver

I have SQL Reporting Services 2005 running on a Win 2008 server with IIS7. SQL and RS have all of the latest patches applied (as of 11/19/2009). When I access a report through Report Manager on the same server or ReportViewer on a different IIS server I can not print.  I get the "unable to load client print control".

This occurs with IE6, 7 and 8. All clients are running with administrative rights. I do get prompted to download the component which seems to occur but then I get the above message.

This same configuration works fine in a test environment, the only difference is the SQL and IIS servers are running Win 2003. 
TIA

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved through applying the latest service packs and any hotfix rollups that were available on 11/21/2009 (SQL server 2005 running on Win 2008)